# Why overflow:hidden is working only in chrome and not in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, sidebar

the overflow:hidden property is working in google chrome and not in firefox and microsoft edge, i'am using it to give full page height to a sidebar so that it will have the same body height.

Style:

```
.sidebar {
   position:absolute;
   width: 225px;
   background-color: #4b4b4b;
   margin-bottom: -5000px;
   padding-bottom: 5000px;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
```

html :

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning {{Request::path()=='home' ? 'selectioné' : ''}}" href="home"><span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning {{Request::path()=='register' ? 'selectioné' : ''}}" href="register"><span>Ajout Compte</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning" href="*******"><span>*******</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning" href="/telescope" target="_blank"><span>Telescope</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning" href="tables.html"><span>Tables3</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link border-bottom border-warning" href="tables.html"><span>Tables4</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

body :

```
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
 }
```

footer:

```
footer {
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 12px;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: calc(100% - 225px);
   height: 80px;
   background-color: #e2e2e2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 28px;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
```

main:

```
.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 225px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

how can i make this work in all browsers ?

Comment: can you also share HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
.sidebar {
  width: 225px;
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom: -5000px; padding-bottom: 5000px;` from `.sidebar` css and add `min-height: 100vh;`, i hope  it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.sidebar {
   position:absolute;
   width: 225px;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-color: #4b4b4b;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: no, it did hide the body overflow which is bad if you have a long body content that was the problem

Comment: i just update the above code, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: no i did not work same thing overflow is not doing its effect

Comment: overflow working fine you just need to remove `padding`, `margin` and add `min-height`. Thanks